# SMAC: Should I use Psi attack?

Tags: alpha-centauri

I am late game Alien Crossfire, attacking with gravitons aremed with [string disruptor](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Sid_Meier%27s_Alpha_Centauri/Weapon#String_Disruptor).

Unfortunately, the others have gotten wise and are building everything [AAA](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Sid_Meier%27s_Alpha_Centauri/Special_Ability#AAA_Tracking). In a way, that's good, as it is expensive, and diverts their resources.

However, I can no longer "one hit kill", and am losing gravitons.

Should I replace the weapons with [Psi attack](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Sid_Meier%27s_Alpha_Centauri/Weapon#Psi_Attack)?

Comment: Or just bypass the AAA by switching to a different chassis that's not airborne.  At your tech level hovertanks should be available, I think.  I'm fond of infantry with drop pods myself.

Comment: That would make a great answer. I was blinkered by the though that graviton were best for traveling acorss a huge map, and had forgotten drop pods. I am now churning out a horde of clean drop string hovercraft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psi attack/defense is orthogonal to conventional weapons. Its result depends on *Morale* levels of attacking/defending units.

If an attacker/defender is a *Mind Worm*, they have their own class, plus both faction's *Planet (Green)* scores/attitudes largely affect the outcome of the fight.

**Answer:** see what's your faction's Morale and/or Green score.

You may also trick the system by changing your *Government/Economy* type before the attack. Say, if you possess some *Mind Worms* and you are planning to give them a victorious ride, switch to *Green* several turns before the planned invasion. Or to *Fundamentalist + Power* if you are planning Psi attacks with conventional units.

---

Personally, I *love* Green because if you are lucky enough, you can capture native life forms, making a considerable amount of your units Mind Worms **(Independent)** which means it requires no support from a home base, still performing as police in "at least one unit defending each Base" paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

If you have dominant weapons, mixing in hovertanks and even air-dropped infantry will let you continue leveraging those dominant weapons.

Psi-combat is mostly useful when facing technologically superior enemies that your weapons cannot defeat.  Switching from overwhelming firepower to psi-attack will make you lose as many (if not more) units, since psi-combat is less lopsided in general.

I'd say consider changing your gravs to transports and using their mobility to deploy slower, ground-based units that ignore AAA. At least until your opponents stop putting all of their eggs in one basket.